# cookies timing out after a minutes or so even though I have it set to 60 minutes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, cookies, asp.net-membership

I've read a handful of posts and I'm not sure if I am missing something but my cookies time out rather quickly.

This is what I have set in my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
  -->
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="suburbanServiceUrl" value=""/>

  </appSettings>

  <system.web>

    <sessionState
      mode="InProc"
      cookieless="false"
      timeout="60"
    />

    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <!-- timeout: Gets and sets the amount of time, in minutes, allowed between requests
                    before the session-state provider terminates the session. -->
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="60"/>
    </authentication>

    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
             connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
             enablePasswordReset="true"
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
             requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="30"
             minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
             minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
             passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="webportal"/>
      </providers>

    </membership>

    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="webportal"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>

    <roleManager enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="webportal"/>
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="webportal"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

    <pages enableSessionState="true">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="Session"/>
      <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>
    </modules>
    <httpProtocol>
    </httpProtocol>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public"
      cacheControlMaxAge="00:00:01" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" />
    </staticContent>   
  </system.webServer>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

</configuration>
```

I took out the connection strings and servicemodel.

In IIS I have this set:

[image]

I believe I have everything set to 60 minutes but it's definitely not lasting that long.

Anyone see what I am missing?

**EDIT**

Sorry, I included the session information in here out of habit when I'm dealing with a timeout issue. Anyhow, as I told Simon Halsey below:

I'm referring to the membership cookie. I am sent back to the login after a min or so. I have [Authorize] on the methods that I'm calling which is sending me back to the login screen after I am inactive for a few minutes

Comment: You might want to remove that password from you config file. You never know what someone might do with it.

Comment: ty thought I got everything. Luckily it's just a dev box in the office.

Answer (score 0):

Which cookie is expiring? You have 2 as far as I can see, Membership cookie & session cookie.

Your Session cookie is a browser session cookie so doesn't have an expiry time set on it - it's only exists whilst the browser is open. When you close the browser, the session cookie is gone. Your session timeout refers to how long the session state lives for on the server. When you close the browser the session lives on until it reaches it's timeout. Since you closed the browser, the corresponding session cookie was destroyed so you can't get that session back. You could hijack the cookie & present it from another browser & this would extend the session.

If you change something, eg the config file, you cause the app to restart & this will kill all active sessions.

Membership cookies work in a similar way. They too are browser session cookies unless you persist the cookie when the user logs in. The membership cookie contains a forms auth ticket which also has an expiry time on it. This time should get extended everytime you visit the site, provided it's within the timelimit set for the ticket.

Comment: I'm referring to the membership cookie. I am sent back to the login after a min or so. I have `[Authorize]` on the methods that I'm calling which is sending me back to the login screen after I am inactive for a few minutes.

Comment: Have you used network tools, like fiddler, or web browser tools to check the request & see what's being passed?

Comment: `[Authorize]` is related to roles checking, not forms auth. it does require you to be logged in if forms auth is enabled, but it's usually used to check the user is in a role. I wonder if this is why you're getting redirected.